# Query regarding the behavior of constant in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am a newbie to tensorflow and I have a question regarding the way the constant function operates.  I have a simple program shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder("float")
b = tf.constant(0.0)

y = tf.mul(x=a,y=b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(y,feed_dict={a:1,b:4}))
```

The output that I get is 4.0. However, I had set 'b' as a constant with value 0.

I was either looking for an error and a value of 0 as the output.  Please help me understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feed_dict` is not only useful to pass value to placeholders, but it can be used to *override* the value of tensors in the graph.

When you run `sess.run(y,feed_dict={a:1,b:4}))` what happens is the filling of the placeholder `a` and the overriding of the constant value `b`.